# C# photo capture device wp8

Tags: c#, out

There is one method in C# photo capture device which is `PhotoCaptureDevice.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr` according to the documentation it is taking one byte array with `out` parameter. However when i try some thing like `captureDevice.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr(out byteArray);` it gives me a compile time error saying `Error    2   Argument 1 should not be passed with the 'out' keyword`. The documentation of the out keyword says that we have to use out key word in both the call and method definition.

[Photo Capture device function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice.getpreviewbufferycbcr%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[out keyword documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

any help will be great thanks

Comment: Is your byteArray initialized?

Comment: i think yes, like that  `byte[] byteArray = new byte[Convert.ToInt32((pWidth * pHeight) + (2 * (totalLength / 4)))];
              
captureDevice.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr(out byteArray);`

Comment: Also i think that `ref` keyword requires the keyword to be initialized before passing

Comment: The Keyword `ref` and `out` are different.

Comment: yeah i know that's why i wrote that `ref` requires the variable to initialized not `out`

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
byte[] byteArray; // Initialization is not required
captureDevice.GetPreviewBufferYCbCr(out byteArray);
```

The **ref** requires that the variable be initialized before being passed not the **out**.